# Trying to get a BrowserView in electron to show the contents of a page

Tags: electron

I have the following code, which works:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView } = require('electron');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    const view = new BrowserView();
    view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 });
    win.addBrowserView(view);
      
    setTimeout(() => {
        view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org');
    }, 1000);
});
```

However, I don't want to use a setTimeout, so I tried it like so:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView } = require('electron');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    const view = new BrowserView();
    view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 });
    win.addBrowserView(view);

    win.on('ready-to-show', () => {
        view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org');
    });
});
```

but that does not show the page.

Is there another event I could use?

Also tried putting the `win.addBrowserView(view)` inside the `ready-to-show` event.

I'm using Electron version 24.1.2 on Windows 10.

I have also tried it on the following versions of node:

- 16.19.0
- 18.13.0
- 19.5.0

**UPDATE**

So much for sample code!

If I setBounds after addBrowserView, I no longer need the timeout or the event:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView } = require('electron');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    const view = new BrowserView();
    win.addBrowserView(view);
    view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 });
    view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org');
});
```

**I TAKE THAT BACK**

Now not working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Finally figured it out.

If I send a message from the renderer process (on DOMContentLoaded event) to the main process and then build and load the BrowserView, it works every time.

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView, ipcMain } = require('electron');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    ipcMain.on('readyToGo', doTheView);
});

function doTheView() {
    const view = new BrowserView();
    view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 });
    win.addBrowserView(view);
    view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the [documentation of BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window) they give a few examples. For instance:

```js
// In the main process.
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

// Load a remote URL
win.loadURL('https://github.com')
```

Comment: loading into BrowserWindow works, but it is a BrowserView that I want to load into